# change style to a null class in js

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

i got a class which is not connected to any tag and i would like to change his attributes via Javascript. That class should be connected to an element only in a specific situation (button click for example).

so, i got this class `azzeccato` and with the changes of the themes the atribute background-color of it should change, but i got an error: null variable, because as i said before it is not connected to any element.

I tried to make it an id element but i didn't find much more luck.

Here is the code:

```js
let theme = document.querySelectorAll('.theme');
let fc = document.querySelector('.Flist');
let azzeccato = document.querySelector('.azzeccato');

/*CHOOSING THEME FUNCTION DOES (IT IS OK)*/
function themes(e) {
  if (e.target == theme[0] || e.target == theme[0].children[0] || e.target == theme[0].children[1] || e.target == theme[0].children[1].children[0]) {
    theme[0].classList.add('backSelection');
    theme[1].classList.remove('backSelection');
    theme[2].classList.remove('backSelection');
    theme[3].classList.remove('backSelection');
    theme[4].classList.remove('backSelection');
  } else if (e.target == theme[1] || e.target == theme[1].children[0] || e.target == theme[1].children[1] || e.target == theme[1].children[1].children[0]) {
    theme[0].classList.remove('backSelection');
    theme[1].classList.add('backSelection');
    theme[2].classList.remove('backSelection');
    theme[3].classList.remove('backSelection');
    theme[4].classList.remove('backSelection');
  } else if (e.target == theme[2] || e.target == theme[2].children[0] || e.target == theme[2].children[1] || e.target == theme[2].children[1].children[0]) {
    theme[0].classList.remove('backSelection');
    theme[1].classList.remove('backSelection');
    theme[2].classList.add('backSelection');
    theme[3].classList.remove('backSelection');
    theme[4].classList.remove('backSelection');
  } else if (e.target == theme[3] || e.target == theme[3].children[0] || e.target == theme[3].children[1] || e.target == theme[3].children[1].children[0]) {
    theme[0].classList.remove('backSelection');
    theme[1].classList.remove('backSelection');
    theme[2].classList.remove('backSelection');
    theme[3].classList.add('backSelection');
    theme[4].classList.remove('backSelection');
  } else {
    theme[0].classList.remove('backSelection');
    theme[1].classList.remove('backSelection');
    theme[2].classList.remove('backSelection');
    theme[3].classList.remove('backSelection');
    theme[4].classList.add('backSelection');
  }
}

/*HERE IS THE PROBLEM*/
if (theme[0].classList.contains('backSelection')) {
  fc.children[0].style.backgroundColor = '#AAAAAA';
  azzeccato.style.backgroundColor = '#2ECC40'; //null class
} else if (theme[1].classList.contains('backSelection')) {
  fc.children[0].style.backgroundColor = '#283747';
  azzeccato.style.backgroundColor = '#DE354C'; //null class
} else if (theme[2].classList.contains('backSelection')) {
  fc.children[0].style.backgroundColor = '#85144b';
  azzeccato.style.backgroundColor = '#FF4136'; //null class
} else if (theme[3].classList.contains('backSelection')) {
  fc.children[0].style.backgroundColor = '#001f3f';
  azzeccato.style.backgroundColor = '#0074D9'; //null class
} else {
  fc.children[0].style.backgroundColor = '#DDAF94';
  azzeccato.style.backgroundColor = '#266150'; //null class
}
```

```css
.azzeccato {
  display: block;
  /*actually i put display hoping to make the whole thing work but it is not the case, so it's not necessary*/
  color: white;
  background-color: #2ECC40;
}

.Flist {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  z-index: 2;
}

.Flist>div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
  /*#932432*/
}

.Flist>div>p {
  color: #F3F3F3;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.Flist>p {
  padding: 10px;
}

.FlistToggle {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*themes DOES NOT CHECK THIS PART IS JUST STYLE*/

.themes {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.theme {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 21%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.theme>p {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.themeRoll {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.backSelection {
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.mezzo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 50px;
  border-top-left-radius: 100px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
}

.green-apple {
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
}

.green-apple>div {
  background-color: #2ECC40;
}

.strawberry {
  background-color: #283747;
}

.strawberry>div {
  background-color: #DE354C;
}

.maroon {
  background-color: #FFDC00;
}

.maroon>div {
  background-color: #85144b;
}

.blue-sky {
  background-color: #0074D9;
}

.blue-sky>div {
  background-color: #001f3f;
}

.tin-olive {
  background-color: #266150;
}

.tin-olive>div {
  background-color: #DDAF94;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="themes">
    <div class="theme backSelection" onclick="themes(event)">
      <p>Green Apple</p>
      <div class="themeRoll green-apple">
        <div class="mezzo"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="theme" onclick="themes(event)">
      <p>Strawberry</p>
      <div class="themeRoll strawberry">
        <div class="mezzo"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="theme" onclick="themes(event)">
      <p>Maroon</p>
      <div class="themeRoll maroon">
        <div class="mezzo"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="theme" onclick="themes(event)">
      <p>Blue sky</p>
      <div class="themeRoll blue-sky">
        <div class="mezzo"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="theme" onclick="themes(event)">
      <p>Tin Olive</p>
      <div class="themeRoll tin-olive">
        <div class="mezzo"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Flist">
    <div>
      <p>COLORS</p>
    </div>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>b</p>
    <p>c</p>
    <p>d</p>
  </div>
  <button style="position:absolute; top:0;left:0;" onclick="fc.children[1].classList.add('azzeccato');">add color</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Do you know how to modify this class?

Comment: Your code can be heavily optimized by using [loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)

Comment: I totally agree with Spectric, but where in you html code do you mention the class azzeccato, because this may be the problem, since at the moment of the error, there is no element in the DOM with this class.

Answer (score 0):

You select the document for .azzecato initially, but you need to requery when the event is fired. Initially, no elements will have that class and the variable will be null, but after the event is fired, this same queryselector should return an element.

Move
`let azzeccato = document.querySelector('.azzeccato');`
into your *themes* function.